# Assign function to a variable in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a **function**(returning String) to a `Text` Widget. If I use getName() directly it works fine.

But if assign the function through a dynamic variable like below, It throws a error. I want to update the name on Button Press.

```
Text(title, style:kText20White),
Button(
 title: 'Change Name',
 onPressed: (){
   setState((){
     value = 1;
   });
 {
)

dynamic title;
int value = 0;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 title = getName;
}

String getName(){
 if(name == 0){
   return 'Taarak';
 } else {
   return 'Harshad';
 }
```

Error:
`type '() => String' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Is it possible to assign String by function through a variable?

Comment: `Text(title(), ...)` instead? The `Text` widget doesn't want a function, it wants a string.

Comment: You can provide a function until it returns String.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying ("until it returns?), can you reword it? Oh, you want to await a network request, asynchronous event or `Future`? Then use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Sorry for my English. I meant 'as long as it returns' String from the function. I don't need to use FutureBuilder since my Strings are static. Check getName() for reference.

Comment: You only want to show `Text` widget when text exists? You can make `getName` return nullable, and use conditional render: inside build, `var name = getName()` and `if (name) Text(name)`

Comment: Not really, as per my usecase, There will always be text on Text Widget. My requirement was to assign function as well as String variable to the Text widget in different situations. This has been now solved by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I understood what you want to do.

You need to check title's variable type and divide calling by type.

Here is final solution!!!

```
Text(title is String ? title : title(), style:kText20White),
Button(
 title: 'Change Name',
 onPressed: (){
   setState((){
     value = 1;
   });
 {
)

dynamic title;
int value = 0;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 title = getName;
}

String getName(){
 if(name == 0){
   return 'Taarak';
 } else {
   return 'Harshad';
 }
```

Comment: This will not help my use case. I've edited my question for better understanding of my usecase.

Comment: I want to assign title with String variable later, but providing () to title will not let me do that. Is it not possible to pass function directly via variable without () to mention on Text widget?

Comment: I updated content after understood what you want to do.

Comment: Enjoy your coding~!

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a function, You have to call function there

```dart
String title;

String getName(){
 return 'First Name';
}

title = getName; //Here you are referencing a function, You have to call function here

Text(title, style:kText20White)
```

**Solution:**

```
title = getName();
```

Try this.

Comment: This will assign the output of getName() to the title, which is non-updatable later. I've edited my question for better understanding of my usecase.

Comment: @VipiNNegi in this case you just have to give variable type annotation as a String, Use String instead of dynamic.